# Best way to prevent fusion in Google Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

From: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#preventing-fusion

> You can insert a GroupByKey and ungroup after your first ParDo. The Dataflow service never fuses ParDo operations across an aggregation.

This is what I came up with in python - is this reasonable / is there a simpler way?

```
def prevent_fuse(collection):
    return (
        collection
        | beam.Map(lambda x: (x, 1))
        | beam.GroupByKey()
        | beam.FlatMap(lambda x: (x[0] for v in x[1]))
        )
```

EDIT, in response to Ben Chambers' question

We want to prevent fusion because we have a collection which generates a much larger collection, and we need parallelization across the larger collection. If it fuses, I only get one worker across the larger collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache Beam SDK 2.3.0 adds the experimental [`Reshuffle`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.3.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/util.py#L516) transform, which is the Python alternative to the `Reshuffle.viaRandomKey` operation mentioned by @BenChambers. You can use it in place of your custom `prevent_fuse` code.

Answer (score 1):

That should work. There are other ways, but they partly depend on what you are trying to do and why you want to prevent fusion. Keep in mind that fusion is an important optimization to improve the performance of your pipeline.

Could you elaborate on why you want to prevent fusion?

Comment: added a comment on motivation

Comment: Why does it depend on what we're trying to do? We want something that says "please don't fuse these", as described in the docs?

Comment: There are different ways to break fusion which have different performance characteristics and are better suited for different cases. For instance, in your case you want to make sure that the parallelism between these transforms isn't dependent (as described in the [Beam Execution Model](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/execution-model/)). This requires the elements to be redistributed between bundles. If you wanted to prevent fusion to decouple failures (also described in the execution model), there are other, possibly lighter weight options.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the clarification. Our biggest issue is that a) processing each item requires a few GB of memory and b) we have some high fan-outs. Should we be approaching this differently? Or continue wrapping any fan-out in this function?

Answer (score 1):

A small adjustment to my original proposal - if each item is too large, that will fail will fail. You need to force them into multiple items, so using a constant key doesn't work. So here, you can supply a `key` function which needs to differentiate the objects and be small, like a hash.

That said, still not sure this is the best way, or whether something simpler (`beam.Partition`?) would work. And would be good for Beam to supply an explicit primitive.

```
def prevent_fuse(collection, key=None):
    """
    prevent a dataflow PCol fusing with the next PCol
    supply a key function if the items are too big to use as keys
    """

    key = key or (lambda x: x)

    return (
        collection
        | beam.Map(lambda v: (key(v), v))
        | beam.GroupByKey()
        | beam.FlatMap(lambda kv: (v for v in kv[1]))
        )
```

Comment: beam.Partition is not what you want -- it divides input elements between separate PCollections. For instance, if you wanted to partition elements that start with a capital letter from those that start with a lower case.

In Java, there is a [Reshuffle.viaRandomKey](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Reshuffle.java#L65) operation which is exactly what you're looking for. Note that a random key works just as well as a hash or anything else.

Comment: Ah great, I had concerns that it could cause issues if a key weren't consistent. So a random key seems dominant in Python, and Reshuffle.viaRandomKey in Java.

Comment: @BenChambers do you want to update your answer so this is synthesized in a single place? I can adjust mine if you have a preference