# How can I maximize throughput for an embarrassingly-parallel task in Python on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to use Apache Beam/Google Cloud Dataflow to speed up an existing Python application. The bottleneck of the application occurs after randomly permuting an input matrix `N` (default 125, but could be more) times, when the system runs a clustering algorithm on each matrix. The runs are fully independent of one another. I've captured the top of the pipeline below:

[image: Pipeline]

This processes the default 125 permutations. As you can see, only the `RunClustering` step takes an appreciable amount of time (there are 11 more steps not shown below that total to 11 more seconds). I ran the pipeline earlier today for just 1 permutation, and the `Run Clustering` step takes 3 seconds (close enough to 1/125th the time shown above).

I'd like the `RunClustering` step to finish in 3-4 seconds no matter what the input `N` is. My understanding is that Dataflow is the correct tool for speeding up embarrassingly-parallel computation on Google Cloud Platform, so I've spent a couple weeks learning it and porting my code. Is my understanding correct? I've also tried throwing more machines at the problem (instead of Autoscaling, which, for whatever reason, only scales up to 2-3 machines*) and specifying more powerful machine types, but those don't help.

---

*Is this because of a long startup time for VMs? Is there a way to use quickly-provisioned VMs, if that's the case? Another question I have is how to cut down on the pipeline startup time; it's a deal breaker if users can't get results back quickly, and the fact that the total Dataflow job time is 13–14 minutes (compared to the already excessive 6–7 for the pipeline) is unacceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pipeline is suffering from excessive [fusion](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#fusion-optimization), and ends up doing almost everything on one worker. This is also why autoscaling doesn't scale higher: it detects that it is unable to parallelize your job's code, so it prefers not to waste extra workers. This is also why manually throwing more workers at the problem doesn't help.

In general fusion is a very important optimization, but excessive fusion is also a common problem that, ideally, Dataflow would be able to mitigate automatically (like it [automatically mitigates imbalanced sharding](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/05/no-shard-left-behind-dynamic-work-rebalancing-in-google-cloud-dataflow)), but it is even harder to do, though some ideas for that are in the works.

Meanwhile, you'll need to change your code to insert a "reshuffle" (a group by key / ungroup will do - fusion never happens across a group by key operation). See [Preventing fusion](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#preventing-fusion); the question  [Best way to prevent fusion in Google Dataflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162365/best-way-to-prevent-fusion-in-google-dataflow) contains some example code.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't able to get the example code running before leaving the office (key too large, and not hashable, either), but I'll read through the stuff you linked and let you know if it worked. Of course, this won't help the fact that it takes a few minutes for the pipeline to even start. Do you know anything that can be done about that?

Comment: Unfortunately, not at this moment. If you need more interactive performance (at the expense of Dataflow's zero-ops), you can try running your code on the Spark runner but it currently only works with Beam Java (but making all runners work with all languages is currently Beam's #1 focus).

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why inserting a `Reshuffle` between `SampleDepths` and `RunClustering` doesn't fix my issue. It's still taking the same amount of time, autoscaling up to 3 workers. Here's my new pipeline: https://i.imgur.com/Gew9Oy3.png (I just upgraded to 2.3.0 and added `| 'PreventFusion' >> beam.Reshuffle()` between the aforementioned steps).

Comment: That being said, if I specify `--num_workers=125 --autoscaling_algorithm=NONE`, my total elapsed time drops to 7–8 minutes, so at least then it isn't running on one worker...

Comment: The Reshuffle helped (the work that previously wasn't parallelized at all, now was somewhat parallelized), just not enough - indeed your job was mostly limited by worker startup time :-/ E.g. it took some time for Dataflow to realize that >1 worker is needed, and then when the worker actually started, some part of the work was allocated to it.

Comment: Autoscaling works better with larger jobs, where the total amount of work is not on the same order of magnitude as worker startup overhead. In your case, specifying number of workers manually may be justified, but 125 is most likely *way* too much - dynamic parallelization is not instant and most likely most of them end up idle most of the time. Try, like, 10? You might see the same performance.

Comment: Yeah, I think I saw about the same performance trying previously with 25 workers as I did with 125. Maybe I can reduce it further. I'll experiment. Out of curiosity, is there any point to specifying `--autoscaling_algorithm=NONE` if I'm already specifying `num_workers`? As long as `num_workers` is specified, I'm getting the performance gain, but I don't see further references to `autoscaling_algorithm` in the Beam codebase to verify the behavior myself (I assume it's handled somewhere in the Dataflow codebase).

Comment: I've gone ahead and accepted your answer, because I think at this point it's more about the specific quirks of my pipeline and problem than the initial issue, which you addressed.