# DataFlow Batch Job Slow / Not Parallelizing Well

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a batch job in Apache Beam 2.2.0 running on DataFlow in Google Cloud, which interacts with Bigtable. The job seems to execute correctly on very small test datasets, but doesn't seem to parallelize well and really under-utilizes the resources thrown at it.

The aim is roughly to achieve the following:

- Given one initial keyword, say name "Bob", find all rows in Bigtable TableA by row-prefix "Bob" (full row schema is something like "Bob*CategoryXXX"
- For each of these rows, find all rows in TableB by the row-prefix "CategoryXXX" (full row schema there is something like "CategoryXXX*ItemIDYYY"
- For each of THOSE rows, find all rows in TableC by the row-prefix "ItemIDYYY"
- Count up all items in that last operation
- Write those results into another table in BigTable

I run this job with 10 n1-standard-1 workers, explicitly disallowing auto-scaling, because in tries to scale things down. CPU utilization on each worker is below 10% and the BigTable instance seems similarly underutilized (virtually zero activity). My custom counters display a tiny bit of progress, so the job isn't stuck, but working really slowly.

Here are the snippets of the relevant code:

```
// Use side inputs to provide the relevant Table ID at each step            
final PCollectionView<String> tableA =
                    p.apply(Create.of("TableA")).apply(View.<String>asSingleton());
            final PCollectionView<String> tableB =
                    p.apply(Create.of("TableB")).apply(View.<String>asSingleton());
            final PCollectionView<String> tableC =
                    p.apply(Create.of("TableC")).apply(View.<String>asSingleton());

            p.apply(Create.of(inputID.getBytes()))  // <- Initial keyword "Bob"
            .apply(ParDo.of(new PartialMatch(configBT, tableA))
                    .withSideInputs(tableA))        
            .apply(ParDo.of(new PartialMatch(configBT, tableB))
                    .withSideInputs(tableB))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new PartialMatch(configBT, tableC))
                    .withSideInputs(tableC))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new GetInfo(configBT)))
            .apply(Sum.<String>integersPerKey())
            .apply(ParDo.of(new LogInfo(configBT)));
            p.run().waitUntilFinish();


    class PartialMatch extends AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn<byte[], byte[]>
    {   
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        final PCollectionView<String> m_tableName;
        private Counter m_ct = Metrics.counter(PartialMatch.class, "matched");

        public PartialMatch(CloudBigtableConfiguration config,PCollectionView<String> side1)
        {
            super(config);
            m_tableName = side1;
        }   

        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(DoFn<byte[], byte[]>.ProcessContext c)
        {
            try
            {
                byte rowKey[] = c.element();
                Scan s = new Scan(rowKey);
                FilterList fList = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
                fList.addFilter(new PrefixFilter(rowKey));
                fList.addFilter(new KeyOnlyFilter());
                s.setFilter(fList); 

                ResultScanner scanner = getConnection().getTable(TableName.valueOf(c.sideInput(m_tableName))).getScanner(s);

                for (Result row : scanner)
                {
                    String rowKeyEls[] = new String(row.getRow()).split(DEF_SPLIT);
                    c.output(rowKeyEls[1].getBytes());
                }
                scanner.close();
                m_ct.inc();
            } catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }

    class GetInfo extends AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn<byte[], KV<String, Integer>>
    {   
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private Counter m_ct = Metrics.counter(GetInfo.class, "extracted");
        private Counter m_ctFail = Metrics.counter(GetInfo.class, "failed");

        public GetInfo(CloudBigtableConfiguration config)
        {
            super(config);
        }   

        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(DoFn<byte[], KV<String, Integer>>.ProcessContext c)
        {
            try
            {
                byte rowKey[] = c.element();

                Result trnRow = getConnection().getTable(TableName.valueOf(DEF_TBL_ID)).get(new Get(rowKey));
                if(trnRow.isEmpty())
                    m_ctFail.inc();
                else
                {                               
                    String b = new String(trnRow.getColumnLatestCell(DEF_CF, DEF_CN_B).getValueArray());
                    String s = new String(trnRow.getColumnLatestCell(DEF_CF,DEF_CN_S).getValueArray());
                    c.output(KV.of(b + DEF_FUSE + s, 1));
                    m_ct.inc();
                }
            } catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }

    class LogInfo extends AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn<KV<String, Integer>, Integer>
    {   
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private Counter m_ct = Metrics.counter(LogInfo.class, "logged");

        public LogInfo(CloudBigtableConfiguration config)
        {
            super(config);
        }   

        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(DoFn<KV<String, Integer>, Integer>.ProcessContext c)
        {
            try
            {
                Table tGraph = getConnection().getTable(TableName.valueOf(DEF.ID_TBL_GRAPH));

                String name = c.element().getKey();
                Integer ct = c.element().getValue();
                tGraph.put(new Put(name.getBytes()).addColumn(DEF.ID_CF_INF, DEF.ID_CN_CNT, Bytes.toBytes(ct)));
                m_ct.inc();
            }catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            c.output(0);
        }
    }
```

What could be slowing things down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things.

- You're creating a separate connection to Bigtable for every single element processed by every function. Instead, put creation of the connection into `@Setup` and closing it into `@Teardown`
- The code currently isn't closing the connections at all, so connections are leaking and that could be slowing it down too.
- Your pipeline is a straight line of ParDo's so they are most likely all fused together and it's suffering from excessive fusion. See the recent answer [How can I maximize throughput for an embarrassingly-parallel task in Python on Google Cloud Platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48848423/how-can-i-maximize-throughput-for-an-embarrassingly-parallel-task-in-python-on-g/48848778?noredirect=1#comment84750882_48848778) . In Java, you can insert `Reshuffle.viaRandomKey()` between your ParDo's.
- Your pipeline is using hand-crafted code to write mutations to BigTable one-by-one. This is inefficient, mutations ought to be batched to maximize throughput. `BigtableIO.write()` does this for you, so I recommend you use it instead of hand-crafted code.

Comment: Thanks re suggestions. I managed to improve the execution by adding an antifuse layer between each ParDo. It looks like Reshuffle.viaRandomKey() is deprecated in Java version 2.2.0? Instead I put in a mix of AntiFuse with random key + GroupByKey + Flatten transforms that you suggested in other posts.

Comment: I also put the getConnection() into the '@setup' and .close() into '@teardown' of each Bigtable-related DoFn. I would prefer to use the build-in BigtableIO sources and sinks, but I can't figure out how to chain them, given that the read sink requires a CloudBigtableScanConfiguration passed to it? For now the overall performance is tolerable, but I still feel that it can be improved a lot

Comment: It's not really deprecated - you can use it. We're just not very happy about it, but it does the job and there's no replacement yet. So it's better to use it than roll your own. Probably time to just unmark it deprecated...

Comment: Not sure what you understand by "chaining" here? I don't think BigTableIO currently supports dynamic key lookups of the sort you're doing (it'd be good if it did though - feel free to file a JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM). But, what do you mean by "read sink"? Sink typically denotes something to which you write.

Comment: haha sorry meant the Read source) What I meant is this: You do BigtableIO.read, then CustomDoFn to parse the row key from that output, then feed its output into another BigtableIO.read. But that last BigtableIO.read would need a CloudBigtableScanConfiguration passed to it in order for it to figure out what rows to read, right? I suppose the CustomDoFn could output those Configurations, which seems like an overkill, but even then, how do I pass it as a parameter to the next BigtableIO.Read()?

Comment: From your colleague's feedback AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn is meant to recycle the once-established connection to Bigtable, so seems like a good workaround to do all these dynamic key lookups?

Comment: Yeah - if a person from the Bigtable team says it's good, then it's good. Though in general this looks like a good motivating case for adding BigtableIO.readAll (like we have e.g. TextIO.readAll(), JdbcIO.readAll() and such)