# Can you programmatically detect re-execution in Google Cloud Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In Google Cloud Dataflow (streaming pipeline), your data "bundles" can be re-executed because of failure or speculative execution. Is there any way of knowing that the current bundle/element is a re-execution?

This would be very useful to provide conditional behavior for side-effects (in our case: to help make a datastore update operation (read/write) idempotent).

Comment: Look at the documentation for [monitoring dataflow via stackdriver logging](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-stackdriver-monitoring#create_alerts_and_dashboards). You can make alerts and monitors for various events and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is something that is offered through the Beam API but you can avoid the need to know this information through following mechanisms.

1. If writes to the external datastore are idempotent, simply introduce a fusion break by adding a [Reshuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162365/best-way-to-prevent-fusion-in-google-dataflow) transform before the write step. This will make sure that data to be written is not re-generated when there are failures.
2. If writes to external datastore are not idempotent (for example, files, BigQuery), usual mechanism is to combine (1) with writing to a temporary location first. When all (parallel) writes to temporary location are finished, results can be finalized in an idempotent and a failure safe way from a single worker.

Many Beam sinks utilize these mechanisms to write to external data stores in an idempotent manner. For streaming, usually, these operations are performed per window.